# How to define type-safe dynamic interfaces in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to find a way to define dynamic interfaces that would allow creating completely type-safe objects. Currently, only the nested object keys are picked up by intellisense, which is only halfway type-safe. When defining a standard JS object, the intellisense works both ways (but it's obviously not type-safe outside the current scope).

```
export interface IDynamicKeysInterface {
  [key: string]: {
    name: string,
    value: number
  };
}

//...

let dynamicKeysObject: IDynamicKeysInterface = {
  a: {
    name: "a",
    value: 0
  },
  b: {
    name: "b",
    value: 0
  }
};

// interface dynamic keys are not highlighted by the IDE
dynamicKeysObject.a.value = 1; // the "value" key is picked up by the IDE
dynamicKeysObject.b.value = 2; // the "value" key is picked up by the IDE
dynamicKeysObject.c.value = 3; // but not the dynamic key, which would break the code

let dynamicKeysObjectJs = {
  a: {
    name: "a",
    value: 0
  },
  b: {
    name: "b",
    value: 0
  }
};

// object keys are highlighted
dynamicKeysObjectJs.a.value = 1; // the "value" key is picked up by the IDE (only in the current scope)
dynamicKeysObjectJs.b.value = 2; // the "value" key is picked up by the IDE (only in the current scope)
dynamicKeysObjectJs.c.value = 3; // the IDE returns a syntax error (but only in the current scope, e.g., function, class)
```

Here is an example describing a more specific scenario (where this question would really be useful) that I'm primarily referring to:

```
class MyFirstClass {
  dynamicKeysObject: IDynamicKeysInterface = {
    a: {
      name: "a",
      value: 0
    },
    b: {
      name: "b",
      value: 0
    }
  };
  fillObject(){
    this.dynamicKeysObject.a.value = 1;
    this.dynamicKeysObject.b.value = 2;
    // from here, the "value" key is picked up by the IDE, but the IDE does not return a syntax error
    this.dynamicKeysObject.c.value = 3;
  }
}

class MySecondClass {
  dynamicKeysObject: IDynamicKeysInterface = {
    a: {
      name: "a",
      value: 0
    }
  };
  fillObject(){
    this.dynamicKeysObject.a.value = 1;
    // from here, the "value" key is picked up by the IDE, but the IDE does not return a syntax error
    this.dynamicKeysObject.b.value = 2;
    this.dynamicKeysObject.c.value = 3;
  }
}

let c1 = new MyFirstClass();
c1.fillObject();
let c2 = new MySecondClass();
c2.fillObject();
```

I can imagine there could be an interface extended for each different object in each class, but that would be so much duplicated code, which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: What do you want to express? That any of the dynamic keys is optional? Or that a particular object has particular keys?

Comment: I would want that after the object is declared with a set of keys, these would be fixed, or at least recognized by intellisense as in the second example

Comment: What "scope" are you talking about where it doesn't work, could you show a case where [this](https://tsplay.dev/mAJa4W) fails to give you IntelliSense?  A [mre] would help a lot.

Comment: @jcalz I've updated the question to define the issue regarding the different scopes. From your TS Playground, I see you are using the `satisfies` keyword. Can you use that in another scope? (e.g., function, class)

Comment: That's a different TypeScript issue. The `satisfies` operator just helps the compiler not forget about the particulars of a value; but inside your `fillObject()` there *are* no particulars; that could be any `IDynamicKeysInterface` whatsoever. Perhaps that means it should warn on *all* keys, but TS by default doesn't work that way. You can enable the `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess` compiler option like [this](//tsplay.dev/Wvqbkm) if you want to be protected against such accesses, or you can redefine the interface like [this](//tsplay.dev/Wyq3xW) to allow for `undefined`.

Comment: Does *that* fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: So the only way would be to define a specific interface for every object having different keys? That's what I'm trying to avoid, but if there's no other way, at least I'd know.

Comment: No, why would you need to define an interface for every object? I don’t see anything I’ve said suggesting such an approach. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @jcalz with your suggestion I see it returns an error for the defined keys too, in the `fillObject` method. I would want it to return an error only for the undefined keys

Comment: `fillObject()` is a method that could receive *any possible* `IDynamicKeysInterface` whatsoever; there are no "defined keys".  It could be called a hundred times with a hundred different inputs, all of which have different keys. How would you like the implementation of `fillObject()` to type check? Are you assuming that `fillObject()` will only ever be called with one particular object? If so, why?  You're not even *calling* `fillObject()` in your example so it's not like you've demonstrated what you're talking about.  What can we do here?

Comment: @jcalz I've updated my question to define a more specific scenario that I'm primarily targeting

Comment: Okay so then does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WyqZKW) meet your needs?  If so I will write up an answer.

Comment: Yes, that seems to do the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, if you [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) the type of a variable or [class field](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#fields), then that's all the compiler will know about the type, even if you assign some value of a narrower type to the variable/field.  The compiler will not retain any knowledge of the narrow assigned value.  (There is an exception if the annotated type is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), in which case [assignments will narrow the apparent type of the variable/field](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#assignments), but your `IDynamicKeysInterface` type is not a union.)

So in this code:

```
class MyFirstClass {
  dynamicKeysObject: IDynamicKeysInterface = {
    a: {
      name: "a",
      value: 0
    },
    b: {
      name: "b",
      value: 0
    }
  };

  fillObject() {
    this.dynamicKeysObject.a.value = 1; // okay
    this.dynamicKeysObject.b.value = 2; // okay
    this.dynamicKeysObject.c.value = 3; // okay but RUNTIME ERROR
  }
}
```

the compiler will not know anything about `dynamicKeysObject` except that it is an `IDynamicKeysInterface`.  Since that type has a `string` [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures), it lets you access any key whatsoever, so you can't tell the difference between `this.dynamicKeysObject.a` which exists and `this.dynamicKeysObject.c` which doesn't.  And if you don't enable [the `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#checked-indexed-accesses---nouncheckedindexedaccess) then the compiler ignores the possibility of the value being `undefined`, so you risk a runtime error when you index into a nonexistent object.  Oops.

---

If you want the compiler to know about the narrower type of the initializer, then you should probably just leave off the annotation entirely and let the compiler infer it for you:

```
class MyFirstClass {
    dynamicKeysObject = {
        a: {
            name: "a",
            value: 0
        },
        b: {
            name: "b",
            value: 0
        }
    };
    fillObject() {
        this.dynamicKeysObject.a.value = 1; // okay
        this.dynamicKeysObject.b.value = 2; // okay
        this.dynamicKeysObject.c.value = 3; // error
    }
}
```

That works just fine.  One drawback of this is that the compiler isn't actually using `IDynamicKeysInterface`, so nothing stops you from violating that type:

```
class MyFirstClass {
    dynamicKeysObject = {
        a: {
            name: "a",
            value: 0
        },
        b: {
            name: "b",
            value: "oops" // <-- no warning here!
        }
    }
}
```

To deal with *that*, you can use [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator).  This checks a value against a type without widening it to that type, so it will allow you to catch mistakes:

```
class MyFirstClass {
    dynamicKeysObject = {
        a: {
            name: "a",
            value: 0
        },
        b: {
            name: "b",
            value: "oops" // error!
        }
    } satisfies IDynamicKeysInterface;
}
```

---

So the final version uses `satisfies` instead of a type annotation:

```
class MyFirstClass {
    dynamicKeysObject = {
        a: {
            name: "a",
            value: 0
        },
        b: {
            name: "b",
            value: 0
        }
    } satisfies IDynamicKeysInterface;
    fillObject() {
        this.dynamicKeysObject.a.value = 1; // okay
        this.dynamicKeysObject.b.value = 2; // okay
        this.dynamicKeysObject.c.value = 3; // error
    }
}
```

and you can do this for different classes with different initializers:

```
class MySecondClass {
    dynamicKeysObject = {
        a: {
            name: "a",
            value: 0
        }
    } satisfies IDynamicKeysInterface;
    fillObject() {
        this.dynamicKeysObject.a.value = 1; // okay
        this.dynamicKeysObject.b.value = 2; // error
        this.dynamicKeysObject.c.value = 3; // error
    }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBECeI4FtgIDSEmAzquNPEsgN4BQyTyA2gNYkBcypYUoAcwC63Bs3HIcuCN178QAgDSMJTAG5wANgFcZk7bgBG0FUwC+Abnpn6thJrilSyALKYAYsCi8Awg6cADHSmyAAm2HgExGQA8oYAVhAIYNwYEfhEJOSUsIgoALzBqkxwoiHFknh6AERw1coV4ho6egHlzGYNxYZljcxSNYb17arNutxtFTbi08wwwJqacYnJABQAlEXFYAAWwKQAdOFSUVnLSWAHcAdjBcgAjBbIAPTPyAD2bHCYI8i7+0d0qdYgkLgdDDctLpkIUAExPV4fL4-Cr-Q7HSKZEErS4ISEtGHIADMCLen2+yEM2jAyAASgBVAByABVUC4AKLIdm02kxWkhGw2Oz+ZxuTzeMB+Ryke5bJgYjLRUjnZKEsTFUpyxoDbi1YZ9dRQ1q-Tq-Hpaio65DVIZdPq3CYmgVWcTzRYqsAbC3MNGAk5Y5Wg5JXfHQwqPF5k5G-X0K4GBnHg0N3eGRpHfGN7dFAgMeg5426Eklp6BQd5QAXWYXS1weLy+EWwrVx3NBmmFdWqTWd7VVXV1O2NB3ISbFU0Vc09y1962235NI2697vAAOpGqaYAPABabeSd7IADucCgIEEyB20AgTpmITdSzbXqnPqzfsxSrz10L4dJ6ZR21fFsPzbJNv2QVNEVLctMwBICzhAgsjSLX8oIrW8hXsGsxXrSURSJZsc2AnE1V+bt536Gc9UHCph1HVRx26XoDStG19QNYdqmXNcN0gqAyygABCG8Oh4OAwH2eYIGcNJ-SVChIFyJAXTmBYHxxJ8YOzWT4MTL8kJ-NNyX-VRY0InSwQhMCIKjDNUUAszsTBRCCUKYteP4yshXoTCnFrcUG2lAAWAjtMc1UO1Ipi+hYgdyMNFpHSmajmEnOLKmkXU5wNZBaOE8xRPE0hJOkrBQuyBTqAgZSmHvD0NLs2CHITME9Jch5fyMzS30Vczg0s-TwI66MGq099etxZNkJLPjoPQ6tfLcABlJJ3hAUIpV8ns4LC9tvRKKLewy61Yuy3KpgFAqJOAKS0FKsayHkqg8mq5BasfTZnyYUyys-SaDMRTqRu6+M836trrOQVCuu25rg2csNiRQma0I6awgA)

Answer (score 2):

You might be better using a `Record` type, you could them make the key Generic and pass the valid keys.

```
type IDynamicKeysInterface<T extends string> = Record<T, {
    name: string,
    value: number
}>


let dynamicKeysObject: IDynamicKeysInterface<'a' | 'b'> = {
  a: {
    name: "a",
    value: 0
  },
  b: {
    name: "b",
    value: 0
  }
} 

dynamicKeysObject.a.name = '';  //ok
dynamicKeysObject.c.name = '';  //error
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=40&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgIiAdgQwLYEsDGBpCIDOMiwEATgGbKYQA8AKlBAB4mIAm%20U%20wp6iA5gD4oAXigAlCJgD2pNvQA0UAN4AoKBqgpUEAFxceffgvWaAbsgA2AVz1brqAEZlVAX0GrPliMChskaFi4BADyjgBWUsD68AEYOHiExGSU1DQA5MjpUAA%20UOmO6cJiahrI%20qWa2nYARMg1JppQFjZ2AAymro1QjhWmGtX6NY4N-c1WtvodGq5uUJ7%202kGJYZGYwAB0yBvVovnpANwaAPTH0gDWqouBCaERURuYO2jQYumHJ8dkpLJAA)

Comment: That works, but not quite perfect from a maintainability perspective. Would there be a way to not have to define the valid keys before the object declaration? (these would not be able to sync when refactoring key names)

Comment: @AlexPredescu None that would also "*work outside the current scope*", like you wanted, e.g. when declaring the return type of a function